# Plotting column average of a 2 dimensional array in matplotlib

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, average

SOLVED: Simple problem that I should really have seen a long time before posting this question. The code worked but I missed an additional line that added the extra plots. I am still new to coding so apologies for the confusion and thanks for the help!

I have two 2-dimensional arrays, for example:

```
a=[[1,2,3],
   [4,5,6],
   [7,8,9]]
b=[[1,2,3],
   [1,2,3],
   [1,2,3]]
```

I have since found the average of each column in each array using:

```
average_a=numpy.mean(a, axis=0).tolist()
average_b=numpy.mean(b, axis=0).tolist()
```

Which resulted in:

```
average_a=[4,5,6]
average_b=[1,2,3]
```

I then tried to used matplotlib to produce a scatter plot of the averages. However, when I tried this I ended up with points corresponding to (1,1),(1,4),(1,7) etc. Anyone able to help me out here?

To test the plot I just tried:

```
import matplotlib as plt

plt.scatter(average_a, average_b)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What code did you use to try to produce the plot? It's hard to tell what went wrong when you haven't provided that code.

Comment: Will add that in as well.

Comment: Added in the edit at the bottom to show what plotting code I was using, apologies

Comment: Are you sure you didn't somehow inadvertently pass in `plt.scatter(a, b)` instead of `average_a, average_b`?  The code you have will plot pairs of (4,1), (5,2), (6,3).  Also, there's no need to call `tolist()`.  Matplotlib will convert the lists you pass in back to arrays, regardless. It's better to pass in the numpy arrays directly.

Comment: I am sure I have plotted the averages against each other, which is why I don't understand. Cheers, will take those out!

Comment: Are you sure that's your code?   I wouldn't have thought `plt.scatter` would even work if you used `import matplotlib as plt`.

Comment: That should be 'import matplotlib.pyplot as plt'. Getting frustrated, apologies once again

Comment: @James: respectfully, you can see why it's hard to be as confident as you are that you're running the code you think you are. :-)  Why don't you make a [*self-contained*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: SOLVED: Simple problem that I should really have seen a long time before posting this question. The code worked but I missed an additional line that added the extra plots. I am still new to coding so apologies for the confusion and thanks for the help!